# Задание по спискам (python)

Tags: python, списки

Ввести с клавиатуры список, содержащий 10 элементов и записать в новый список сначала все четные значения элементов, а потом нечетные. На экран вывести исходный и новый список.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: А вы сами как-то пытались это сделать?

Comment: Используйте более информативный заголовок. Чтобы ваш вопрос мог пригодиться кому-нибудь ещё (цель существования сайта), задайте *отдельный* вопрос о каждой части, которую не понимаете как сделать. К примеру 1- "как ввести список из 10 целых чисел с клавиатуры" 2- "как определить является ли число чётным" 3- "как получить новый список, с чётными элементами впереди нечётных" 4- "как вывести список на экран в Питоне"

Answer (score 3):

1. Для ввода элементов команда `input` либо как аргумент.
2. Для создания списка команда `list`.
3. Четные элементы делятся на `2` без остатка.
4. Вывести результат на экран команда `print`

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = [int(input()) for i in range(10)]  # сохраняем вводимые данные
sortedLst = sorted(lst, key=lambda item: item % 2)  # сортируем по четности

print(lst)  # вывод исходного списка
print(sortedLst)  # вывод отсортированного
```

Answer (score 0):

Как реализовать? Да вот так, например:

```
a = [int(input('Input number ' + str(i) + ': ')) for i in range(1, 11)]
print(a)

b = [x for x in a if x % 2 == 0] + [x for x in a if x % 2 != 0]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_1 = list(map(input, range(10)))
def sort_list(i: int):
    return i & 1  # True - нечетные
list_2 = list(sorted(map(int, list_1), key=sort_list))
```